# Random selection from an array

Tags: php, arrays

There is this function :

```
mt_rand(1,5)
```

=> randomly selects between 1 and 5.

and another method:

```
$items = array(1, 4, 5, 7, 8);
echo $items[array_rand($items)];
```

My question is about second method. 
I want to use it in this way. `echo array_rand(1,4,5,7,8);`

Is there a way to do this, or how can I do it? I would like to use the function **without** defining the array first. Everything in one place. thanks!

Note: I want to use it for unordered list.

Comment: Do you mean simply like `echo array_rand(array(1,4,5,7,8))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can flip the array, then use `array_rand()`, this will inverse the key-value pairs (so the key becomes the value, and vice-versa). This will mean that when you use `array_rand()`, you get the new key - which was originally the value.

```php
echo array_rand(array_flip($items));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/7RSVY

If you want to define a function with a variable number of parameters, you can do that too, by using `func_get_args()`.

```php
function random_value() {
    // If there were no values returned, return false.
    if (func_num_args() == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // Get all the values supplied
    $values = func_get_args();
    $random = array_rand($values);
    return $values[$random];
}
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/b63WX

Though you can just define the array inline, by doing

```php
echo array_rand(array_flip([1, 3, 7, 8]));
```

Comment: Thanks. but I don't want to define the array $items = array(1, 4, 5, 7, 8); beforehand. I seek a way to use the array and the function together in one place.

Comment: I don't get it - how do you expect to determine the values (1, 4, 5, 6, 8)?  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In my example above, i gave a psedo code, something like this : echo array_rand(1,4,5,7,8);  this is not correct obviously.

Comment: So, you want it to be a function?

Comment: I'd like it to be all in one place. I write the function array_rand and the numbers together. Instead of defining an array first, then passing the array to the function.

Comment: I've updated the answer, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Thanks, Qirel. This is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use helper function

You can add helper function:

```
function arr_rand($array){    
    return $array[array_rand($array)];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't use a string. I want to keep it simple, and easier to manipulate. but I couldn't find a way to do it after some search and tries.

Comment: You can write a helper function. I have edited my answer